# nesting an alter system in an if statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to automate setting restricted mode and unsetting restricted mode for my organization. The following code was my attempt:

```
DECLARE
v_sess VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
SELECT LOGINS
INTO v_sess
FROM $V_INSTANCE;
IF UPPER(v_sess) = 'RESTRICTED' THEN
ALTER SYSTEM DISABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
END IF;
END;
```

But i get the following error:

> ERROR at line 8: ORA-06550: line 8, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered
>   the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case
>   declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select
>   update while with    << continue close current
>   delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute
>   commit forall merge pipe purge

please help me understand where i went wrong. and if this isnt possible then its a really easy fix of me not trying. :)

Comment: What's the RDBM you're using?

Comment: @User2012384 going by the error message, it's Oracle. Added a tag. Gooberturkey, please add this tag in future (assuming it's correct)!

Comment: Who granted you access? - I want to see that person

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks for the advice. you were right it is oracle. and i will add the tag as requested in future.

Comment: @T.S. Since you didnt know the full context. I appreciate the upfront criticism without the attempt at understanding my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without commenting on the wisdom of what you are trying to do, try this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SYSTEM DISABLE RESTRICTED SESSION';
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew. That was all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have an external sql file to change the restriction mode. The database is taken into restricted for different reasons and changing it in pl/sql is not recommended.

Create a sql file that has your alter statement and invoke it via sqlplus. If it needs to be scheduled, use a cron job or chain it to the event that takes it into restricted mode.

Comment: I am creating a shl script to cleanup our source tree and disable restricted session if it is enabled after we do our upgrades to the DB. my script takes a parm from the user and determines if they wanted to unrestrict it and if so it then checks to see it if was restricted to start with because user error is high in my workplace. thanks.